# How can I install Pygame to Pycharm?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

I recently installed pycahrm, I installed PIP and tried to install Pygame. There wasn't a just "Pygame" but there were sound effects and other things for it. What I really want is to install Pygame onto my pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you already have an interpreter for PyCharm. To be able to let PyCharm recognize PyGame, you will need to have download an interpreter that has PyGame installed with it. There is no other way. Maybe go to Google and find the right interpreter that has PyGame included within it. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 2):

My friend just showed me what I need to do. Apparently I just need to install it from the Pygame site's installer. Mystery solved.

Comment: any detailed answer? i m doing same thing - i want to develop in pygame using pycharm, how do i do it?